# How to rerun only failed tests in go testing

Tags: go, testing, automated-tests

I have a package with several files and tests. Currently to rerun failed tests I'm using:

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    var r int = -1
    maxRuns := 3
    for i := 0; i < maxRuns && r != 0; i++ {
        r = m.Run()
    }
    os.Exit(r)
}
```

Actually it works, however it reruns all package tests in a single test failure scenario. So sometimes it leads to the next sequence: PASSED,PASSED,FAILED. This way the test marked as FAILED.
My goal is to rerun only failed tests in a package, mark it as PASSED at the moment of a first success, mark test as FAILED only in case of a triple failure. Any suggestion?

Comment: The testing package is not designed to do that. In particular not enough stuff is exported. See the source code at https://golang.org/src/testing/testing.go and note the comments currently at line 1310, near the top of `func (m *M) Run()`. This calls `runTests` (not exported) which calls each test whether or not it's already marked failed.

Comment: "mark test as FAILED only in case of a triple failure" is not normal, so it's not supported by the testing library. You could write an individual test to do this yourself, but if all of your tests need to work this way, your tests are the issue. Unit tests should be repeatable and deterministic to be useful; they should always yield the same results unless the code changes.

Comment: The thing it's not unit tests. I'm trying to implement e2e tests via go. So tests may failed sometimes.
In other languages like Python for instance there are good test frameworks, I'm just trying to find something similar in go.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably long answered, but the way I've seen this for integration tests is wrapping the retry code in a function that takes a callback to your test implementation. This is particularly helpful if you're making API calls and have things where `context.Done` would be needed to check for hanging calls or timeouts. For example: https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/util/retry

Here's a simple example.

```
func MyPolicy(ctx context.Context, t *testing.T, retries int, testImpl func(context.Context, t *testing.T)) error {
  for i := 0; i < retries; i++ {
    err := testImpl(ctx, t)
    if err != nil {
      t.Logf("Test error: %v", err)
      continue
    }
    return nil
  }
  return fmt.Errorf("Retry budget of %d attempts exhausted", retries)
}


func TestIntegration(t *testing.T) {
  impl := func(ctx context.Context, t *testing.T) error {
   // implement here calling t.Logf when needed not t.Fatal/Error
  }

  if err := MyPolicy(context.Background(), t, 3, impl); err != nil {
    t.Fatalf("Test failed with: %v", err)
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you cannot or don't want to change the code of original test case (e.g. writing a test framework or maintaining old projects)...

my way is using subtests (but ensure not parallel, otherwise you need to control the retry logic yourself, more a bit complex but still can do)

quite hacking, i suggest not to use it unless nothing else helps

```golang
passed := false
for i := 0; i < 3 && !passed; i++ { // retry 3 times
  passed = t.Run("retry-able subtest", func(t *testing.T) {
    // e2e test may fail, copied or wrapped from origin case
  })
}

// since we want the whole test to be success after retry-success, we can hack the result... and this is not worked in parallel since the `passed` will not be the real test result under parallel mode
if passed {
    res := reflect.ValueOf(t).Elem().FieldByName("failed")
    hackedRes := reflect.NewAt(res.Type(), unsafe.Pointer(res.UnsafeAddr())).Elem()
    hackedRes.Set(reflect.ValueOf(false))
}
```